# What is meaning of 'Blocking' in Firebug Net Panel?

Tags: firefox, firebug, blocking

I'm using Firebug 1.5.2 and while testing a site before production release i can see a huge amount of time consumed by 'Blocking' parts of the requests.

What exactly does the 'Blocking' mean?

Answer (score 29):

"Blocking" previously (earlier versions of FireBug) was called "Queuing". It actually means that request is sitting in queue waiting for available connection. As far as I know number of persistent connections by default is limited in last versions of Firefox to 6, IE8 also 6. Earlier it was only 2. It can be changed by user in browser settings.
Also as I know that while javascript file is loading, all other resources (css, images) are blocked

Comment: I'd just like to add that this is why you should load javaScript files last (if possible). The page will seem to load much faster to the user if it doesn't have to wait for CSS or images to load.

Comment: Also see the corresponding [official documentation by Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Network_Monitor#Timings).

Answer (score 5):

Blocking is a term used to describe an event that stops other events or code from processing (within the same thread).

For example if you use "blocking" sockets then code after the socket request has been made will not be processed until the request is complete (within the same thread).

Asynchronous activities (non blocking) would simply make the request and let other code run whilst the request happened in the background.

In your situation it basically means that certain parts of firebug / the browser cannot activate until other parts are complete.  I.e. it is waiting for an image to download before downloading more.

Comment: Is it possible to setup Apache server to remove such blocking issues? I'm sure that server can do it because almost all IIS sites dont have such blocking delays, but "clean" apache installation does it...

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know, two reasons cause components to cause blocking others from loading.

1. Browser's enforced (but usually configurable) limit of how many parallel resources can be loaded from a particular host at a time.
2. Inline javascript, which can cause the browser to wait and see if it at all needs to go ahead with downloading the rest of the components (just in case the javascript redirects or replaces the content of the page)

Answer (score 2):

**It means "waiting for connection".** As explained in the official [documentation by Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Network_Monitor#Timings), "Blocking" is "Time spent in a queue waiting for a network connection." That can be due to Firefox hitting its internal parallel connections limit, as explained there and in answers here.

**It can also mean "waiting because server is busy".** One possible reason for "Blocking" times is missing in the official documentation linked above: it can happen when the server cannot provide a connection at the time because it is overloaded. In that case, the connection request goes into a queue on the server until it can be processed once a worker process becomes free [[source](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mpm_common.html#maxrequestworkers)].

In a technical sense, such a connection is not yet established because the request is awaiting `accept()` from the server [[source](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11126372)]. And maybe that is why it is subsumed under "Blocking" by Firefox, as it could also be considered "Time spent in a queue waiting for a network connection".

(This behaviour is not fully consistent as of Firefox 51 though: for the first URL called up in a new tab, the time before the server accepts the connection request is not counted at all in the "Timings" tab – only for subsequent URLs entered. Either of both behaviours could be a bug, I don't know which one.)