# What do the colored bars in the Firefox net panel represent?

Tags: firefox, firebug

In the firefox developer tools, under the "Net" panel, resources that are loaded have their load time split into different colors/categories. These are:

- DNS Lookup
- Connecting
- Blocking
- Sending
- Waiting
- Receiving

What do each of these represent, and more specifically, does any of them accurately represent the amount of time that the server is thinking (accessing the database, running algorithms, etc)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You couldn't accurately determine what the server is doing as such, I'm afraid.

You can discount most of them except Waiting, however, as the rest occur before and after the server handles your request. What it actually does while you wait will be a 'black box'.

There may be some asynchronous operations taking place during Sending and Receiving, so again it's hard to be accurate but you can get a ballpark figure of the time the server is working and the time the request spends travelling back and forth.

**EDIT**

Rough Definitions:

*DNS Lookup*: Translating the web address into a destination IP address by using a DNS server
*Connecting*: Establishing a connection with the web server

*Blocking*: Previously known as 'queueing', this is explained in more detail [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2498541/what-is-meaning-of-blocking-in-firebug-net-panel)

*Sending*: Sending your HTTP Request to the server

*Waiting*: Waiting for a response from the server - this is where it's probably doing all the work

*Receiving*: Getting the HTTP response back from the server

Comment: so 'waiting' does try to approximate the amount of time the server is thinking before it's first flush of data is sent to the browser?

Comment: Approximate is the key word here! You might not be waiting for it to do _your_ work, of course but you can at least eliminate the time spent sending and receiving data and establishing connections from the equation.

Comment: Maybe it has changed, but now the new Firefox dev tools uses DNS Lookup, Connecting, Sending, Waiting, Receiving. Safe to say that Connecting == Blocking and they've just changed the name again?

Answer (score 4):

The [firebug wiki](http://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Net_Panel) also explains these (see the Timeline section).

- **Blocking** Time spent in a browser queue waiting for a network
  connection (formerly called Queueing). For SSL connections this includes the SSL Handshake and the OCSP validation step.
- **DNS Lookup** DNS resolution time
- **Connection** Elapsed time required to create a TCP connection
- **Waiting** Waiting for a response from the server
- **Receiving** Time required to read the entire response from the server
  (and/or time required to read from cache)
- **'DOMContentLoaded' (event)** Point in time when DOMContentLoaded event was fired (since the beginning of the request, can be negative if the request has been
  started after the event)
- **'load' (event)** Point in time when the page load event was fired (since the beginning of the request, can be negative if the request has been started after the event)

Answer (score 0):

There's a pretty good article with time charts and a protocol level explanation of what's happening at each stage [here](http://blog.catchpoint.com/2010/09/17/anatomyhttp/).I found it pretty helpful as they also visually demonstrate the impact of using persistent and parallel connections versus serial connections.