# What we mean by waiting time in the firefox developer tools

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, timeline, firefox-developer-tools

I am using the Firefox developer tools to understand the my application network calls from the client to server , in this i am checking the Network -> TImings tab , can someone given what below field represent

```
Sending
Waiting
Receiving
```

and what it represent if the Waiting time is toooooo much value than receiving time , for example

```
waiting time is 10.3 sec
receiving time is 2 ms only
```

if waiting time is tooo much , that means is server is side code is not performing well ? , mean this waiting time is related to server side processing , how fast the server side is processing the request ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What do the colored bars in the Firefox net panel represent?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5652198/what-do-the-colored-bars-in-the-firefox-net-panel-represent)

Answer (score 7):

**Sending** is basically Time taken to send the HTTP request to the server.

**Waiting** is the total wait time (by client) before receiving first byte of response from the server. This is equivalent of **TTFB** (in chrome dev tools)

**Receiving** is the time taken to read the entire response from the server (and/or time required to read from cache). In chrome dev tools it is termed as **Content-Download** time.

Please check [Mozilla's documentation on Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Network_Monitor) for further details.

Answer (score 4):

**Sending**: Processing of sending the request to the server.

**Waiting**: The amount of time waiting for a response from the server (i.e. the time between when the request was sent and response received).

**Receiving**: The time for processing the receipt of the response to the request.

There are a variety of possible issues for larger Waiting times. Figuring out what is causing it can be quite involved. Server side code not performing well is one possibility. What you do know is that during this time your computer is just waiting for the response from the server.

Answer (score 0):

From the [MDN docs on request timing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Network_Monitor/request_details#Request_Timing):

```
Sending     Time taken to send the HTTP request to the server.
Waiting     Waiting for a response from the server.
Receiving   Time taken to read the entire response from the server (or cache).
```